# Resume AVAudio session after interruption

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, ios-background-mode

**Issue:**

My application's audio is not resuming after an interruption (such as phone call or when I use other applications). This issue happens when my application is already in the background state before the interrupt occurs.

**Code to handle interrupts:**

```
- (void)handleInterruption:(NSNotification *) notification{
    if (notification.name != AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification || notification.userInfo == nil) {
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary *info = notification.userInfo;

    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification]) {

        if ([[info valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan]]) {


            NSLog(@"InterruptionTypeBegan");

        } else {
            NSLog(@"InterruptionTypeEnded");
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"playing audio");

               self->_audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
               [self->_audioPlayer play];

            });
        }
    }
}
```

In Xcode console, I see logs in the following sequence but no audio is played:

1. InterruptionTypeBegan
2. InterruptionTypeEnded
3. playing audio

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I have noticed the same issue with many online music streaming apps such as Saavn and Spotify.

Comment: So you are saying `self->_audioPlayer play` at a time when your app is in the background and not playing?

Comment: Yes, matt. The audio is not playing.

Comment: Are you reactivating your audio session? What category is your session?

Comment: The AVAudioSession category is set to "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback". I tried reactivating the audio session in the interrupt end block, but it has no effect.

Comment: @matt Please refer to the edit section.